# tomatousb - Allow only specific IP to connect to other IP port

Tags: networking, router, firewall, iptables, tomato

I'm using tomato shibby on a router, and I'm trying to set some specific rules using iptables to set the following:

I have a server, which runs on 192.168.1.2 (LAN) port 2232.
Everybody from the LAN can access it. I want to make sure the server is accessible port 2232 **ONLY** by 192.168.1.3

I've set the following iptables rules. Like I said I'm using tomato shibby, and I've set this rules in Administration->Scripts->Firewall:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 2232 -s 192.168.1.3 -d 192.168.1.2 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 2232 -d 192.168.1.2 -j DROP
```

The first rule should accept my client IP: 192.168.1.3 to access the server running on 192.168.1.2 port 2232, and the second rule should drop the packets that are sent by other IPs.

I've rebooted the router after I've set the changed, and I can still access my server, from other IPs. I've checked via ssh if the iptables were actually set by the web gui, and they did.

**UPDATE:**
Rules, shown by `iptables -L`

**UPDATE2:**
The *Access Restriction* does a good job in creating rules, but it looks like they are applied only to what goes through WAN. It doesn't work with restrictions inside the LAN.

```
ACCEPT     tcp  --  192.168.1.3         192.168.1.2       tcp dpt:2232 
DROP       tcp  --  anywhere             192.168.1.2       tcp dpt:2232
```

I'm not sure if I need to somehow *init*  the rules too, but I don't think so.

Any suggestions are appreciated.